# How to index a 3D tensor with another 3D tensor?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

For example, if I have an input tensor: 
`x = [[[0, 1], [2, -1]], [[5, 1], [-10, -100]]]` batch x 2 x 2 dimensionality 
and a indices tensor: 
`ind = [[[1], [0]], [[0], [0]]]` 
How to go about indexing x with ind in order to obtain: 
`out = [[[1], [2]], [[5], [-10]]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`torch.Tensor.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.gather.html#torch.Tensor.gather)

```py
x = torch.tensor([[[0, 1], [2, -1]], [[5, 1], [-10, -100]]])
ind = torch.tensor([[[1], [0]], [[0], [0]]])

out = x.gather(2, ind)
```

which results in

```
>>> out
tensor([[[  1],
         [  2]],

        [[  5],
         [-10]]])
```